# In Oracle, why is '' = '' false?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

This question comes from my previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10936176/searching-for-text-in-a-database-with-entity-framework).

I'm curious as to why:

```
select * from TPM_USER where '' = ''
```

Returns zero rows, however:

```
select * from TPM_USER where 1 = 1
```

Returns every row in the table.  Is this per SQL standard, or is this Oracle specific?

Oracle [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/74757/5).

The following work as expected:

PostgreSQL [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/66640/1)

SQL Server [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/66640/1)

mySQL [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/66640/1)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Oracle, an [empty string equates to NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203493/why-does-oracle-9i-treat-an-empty-string-as-null). You [don't use `=` for NULL values](http://thinkoracle.blogspot.com/2005/06/nulls-in-oracle.html).

Comment: Nope, that results in `ORA-00908: missing NULL keyword`

Comment: Thanks. The rest of my comment is still true.

Comment: Thanks, `+1` from me.  Justin Cave's answer in your linked question explains the history behind this perfectly.

Answer (score 7):

Oracle does not distinguish between empty string and `NULL`.

That's why the recommended string datatype is `VARCHAR2` and not `VARCHAR`: the latter is supposed to do this distinction but currently does not.

In trivalent logic which `SQL` uses, `NULL = NULL` (which in Oracle is synonymous to `'' = ''`) evaluates to `NULL` (not `FALSE` but `NULL`) and hence is filtered out by the `WHERE` clause.